# При прокрутке лайаута scrollview прятать клавиатуру

Tags: java, android

Необходимо скрывать клавиатуру,когда происходит скролл или вверх или вниз.
Делаю так:
*кусок кода разметки*

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollViewcontent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.handlingcitizen.handlingcitizen.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
```

в активности пишу:

```
public void hideKeyborScroll() {
    mScrollView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                onClickAway();

        }
    });
}

protected void onClickAway() {
    if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
                (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

}
```

реакции ноль при прокрутке.

Может это важно:
в манифесте прописал `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`
**этот параметр важен для меня**,
в разметке для edittext (10шт)у всех свой-ва

```
android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: Возможно вам надо не по событию смены фокуса скрывать клаву, а по событию скрола? setOnScrollListener

Comment: @ЮрийСПб
т.е все тоже самое,но только обработчик менять?

Comment: Да, типа того. Но надо пробовать - могут разные проблемы вылезти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final Activity activity = YourActivity.this;
            final View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
            if (view != null) {
               final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать на определенный EditText вот этот код:

```
YourEditText.clearFocus();
```